# Content based recommender system with sklearn or numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build a content-based recommender system in python/pandas/numpy/sklearn.

Here are the matrix involved and their size:

X: n_customers * n_features (contains the features of each customer)

Y: n_customers *n_products (contains the scores given by each customer to each product)

Theta: n_features * n_products

The aim is to learn Theta in order to be able to predict the score given by a customer to all products (X*Theta). Indeed, Y is a sparse matrix, a customer score only a very small % of the whole quantity of products. This is why Y contains a lot of NaN values.

Here is my problem:

This is a regression problem with many targets (here target=product). But I want to do the regression only on not null values. because the number of NaN differ from one product to another, how can I vectorize that ?

Assume there are 1000 products and 100 000 customers, each one having 20 features.

For each product I need to the regression on the not null values. So without vectorization, I would need 1000 different regressor learning each one a Theta vector of length 20.

If possible I would like to solve this problem with sklearn. The ridge regression for example takes into account multiple targets (Y as a matrix)

I hope it's clear enough.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am not sure why you have null values there, any `scipy.sparce` matrix represents missing value with 0. Also, you have no idea how many and what product features are there, right?

Comment: Actually Y is a DataFrame I built from a pivot command in pandas. I used the term sparse to highlight the fact that each customer rate only a few products (from 2 to 6 for examples) while there are more than 1000 products. I have features (lets say 20) for each customer. This is represented in the X DataFrame (n_customers*n_features). All features about customers are known

Comment: From what your problem looks like, I would not recommend the `sklearn.linear_model.ridge` regression objects. Yes, they are multi-target, but as of now, these targets cannot be linked or share information in any way via e.g. a covariance matrix. Since your problem has many missing values, it is crucial to implicitly or explicitly use information shared between your target products.

Have you looked into matrix completion techniques? This is not exactly what you are trying to do, but may help. You could for example stick X and Y horizontally together and try to impute missing values.

Answer (score 1):

I believe You can use centered cosine similarity /pearson corelation to make this work and make use of collaborative filtering technique to achieve this

Before you use pearson co -relation you need to fill the Null ( the fields which dont have any entries) with zero ,now pearson co relation centers the similarity matrix around zero ,which gives optimum recommendation .